# How to pass session id to cookie data using JMeter?

Tags: jmeter-4.0

I'm new to JMeter and want to know how to pass session-id to all httpRequests.

I have tried with cookieManager and then HttpRequest is having session-id but response shows "session expired".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cookie manager and Post Processor will solve the problem.

For example-

below opensrm is transaction controller

Add HTTP Cookie Manager and add Post Processor in the request to extract the result as below.

[image]

Below is a Boundary extractor I used to extract the value of the session ID from the response.

Refer this for [Boundary Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Boundary_Extractor)

[image]

Now we will use this variable to initialize cookie in Cookie Manager

[image]

sessionID is a variable used to store extracted session id from the response in Boundary extractor.

For how to use HTTP Cookie manager https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager

FYI: Cookie manager should be used where ever the session id is used in requests.